# как выделить в тексте слова, которые больше всего повлияли на классификацию текста keras?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, текст, keras

Есть следующая нейросеть, обученная классифицировать текст на 2 класса:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC
from tensorflow_addons.metrics import F1Score

batch_size = 16
num_neurons = 200

n_model = Sequential()
n_model.add(LSTM(num_neurons, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(maxlen, emb_dims)))
n_model.add(Dropout(.2))
n_model.add(Flatten())
n_model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
n_model.compile('rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Текст переведен с помощью word2vec в вектор, размер вектора одного текста (1, 100, 200)

Можно ли в тексте выделить слова, которые больше всего повлияли на классификацию текста?

В RandomForest это feature_importances. Как можно сделать аналогично?